# Where do I input my SQL commands in a XAMPP like simulator?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I'm pretty new to the world of internet coding. I've taken a few courses on how to code in HTML and CSS, and I've read up on quite a bit of JavaScript, but I'm struggling with mySQL and PHP. I'm using Brackets to code my pages, but I want to know if there is a way to dirictly code mySQL in my PHP file (such as "CREATE DATABASE") instead of use the UI in http://localhost:8012/phpmyadmin where you can create databases and all of the works. I'm using XAMPP to simulate my server. I've looked into w3schoools (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) tutorial on how to code in SQL, and I must say, I feel pretty proficient, but I just don't know where to input the code.

Thanks so much in advance, and I'd love to learn any little bit of information that you have to share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to both StackOverflow and the "world of internet coding" as you like to call it.

There certainly is! It is called [PHP Data objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). More precisely [PDO::exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) might be your friend in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [PHP's mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). With it you can [connect to a database](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and [send queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) in native PHP. And lots more!

If you're used to using phpMyAdmin you may want to brush up on your MySQL syntax. You have to write out commands like `mysqli_query("CREATE TABLE tablename");`.